# Basic javascript questioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a script to dynamically change a textarea content.

After some Googling I got this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // This is a first text modification that works fine
    $('textarea#modifyme').val('Some useless text');

    // Catching a select change
    $('select#changemyvalue').bind('change keyup input',function() {
        // This alert triggers but twice
        alert('I know you want to change text');
        // This is not displaying...
        $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
    });
});
```

First value setting is good, but when it comes to select change detection it gets a bit odd.
Alert is triggering twice, and the second value setting is not functioning.

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

---

Thanks to your answers I've fixed the double trigger, but still the secon .val('sometext') is not triggering.

I'm trying to apply this to a textarea displaying as a wysiwyg editor, I can only change the text on load (first .val('xx') call).

I also notice that if I invert these 2 lines :

```
// This alert triggers now only once
alert('I know you want to change text');
// This is not displaying...
$('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
```

To :

```
// This is not displaying...
$('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
// This alert does not trigger if placed here
alert('I know you want to change text');
```

Code seem to break at the first line, preventing 'alert' to display.

Is the nature of wysiwyg editor preventing text change after page load?

---

Here is the short version of html code :

```
<select name="" id="selectMe">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<textarea class="textarea callhtml5" name="changeMe" id="changeMe"></textarea>

<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="path to wysihtml5 bootstrap"></script>

<script>
    $(".callhtml5").wysihtml5();
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('textarea#changeMe').val('Initial text setup');
    $('select#selectMe').bind('change keyup',function() {
        alert('Test');
        $('textarea#changeMe').val('Final text setup');
    });
});
<script>
```

---

Solved this problem by using :

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').html("I got you modified");
```

Instead of this method :

```
$('textarea#changeMe').val('Final text setup');
```

Comment: Please, could you add the html?

Comment: `bind('change keyup input',...` Never heard about `input` event. What is it?

Comment: @hindmost, like this [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: @Grundy Ok, but is it applicable to `select`?

Comment: @hindmost, yes, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/4y99kjdo/

Comment: @Grundy I get `change` logged in console, but not `input` (FF 44)

Comment: @hindmost, in chrome work both, can you check snippet in my answer?

Comment: I don't think input event can be captured.

Comment: @Jai, i check in a few browsers: Chrome, FF,IE, EDGE, and _input_ hanlde just in Chrome. Interesting, is this a bug or feature? :-)

Comment: @grundy just read the docs and it is fully supported in chrome and Firefox but this is interesting that select is actually firing input event. May be a bug or implementation. Can't say it's bad or good. But I think it shouldn't fire on this element.

Comment: Please find a better title to your question. Also, when it is solved rather check the one answer as the solution than prepending *solved* to the title - this is not how SO works!

Answer (score 2):

It's because of `keyup` and `input`. If you bind both events the callback executes two times.

To over come this use these two `bind input`. You can omit the `keyup`.

One thing I would like to mention about `input` event is that it can't be captured. What I mean is it won't let you capture event.

---

Just noticed that the element is `<select>` element so better to use `change keyup`. You should avoid using `input` event as you are not putting text values in it but changing it with mouse or keys.

Comment: i think rather _change_ and _input_

Comment: 'Change' is much better

Comment: @RIYAZKHAN `change` event happens when you leave the input. You have to put focus out of that element.

Comment: @riyazkhan well last comment I should edit but you are correct as the elemt is a select element so change event is enough. But seems that op want to capture if value change happens with arrow keys etc. I guess.

Comment: *"One thing I would like to mention about input event is that it can't be captured."* - That's not true. Perhaps you should expand on that statement to clarify which elements the input event applies to and/or which browsers support it - you certainly *can* have an "input" change handler for some form elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I got this part of the code from a guy showing how to catch events from an input. I left change and keyup but still, last part of the code is not functionning. I can't figure why the second .val('somestring') is not triggering... I'm trying to change a textarea displaying as a wysiwg editor, could this be the reason why I can't modify this after an event? Is it only possible to set this on page load?

Comment: And if I invert the order of these 2 lines  from :
    // This alert triggers but now once
    alert('I know you want to change text');
    // This is not displaying...
    $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
to :
    // This is not displaying...
    $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
    // This alert triggers but now once
    alert('I know you want to change text');

I got absolutely nothing running, alert is not showing and text area change is not happening...

Answer (score 1):

You need to either take out `change` or `input` from `.bind()`. Both events are triggering thus running the function twice.

Hope this helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

*As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.* http://api.jquery.com/bind/

You could probably change your code like this to work.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('textarea#modifyme').val('Some useless text');

    $('select#changemyvalue').on('change', 'keyup', 'input',function() {
        alert('I know you want to change text');
        $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
    });

  });
```

**EDIT:** Instead to using three things, one would work properly. Use `input` or `keyup`

Comment: The bind() method is still supported, and for a simple (non-delegated, etc.) case does exactly the same thing as the on() code that you've suggested.

Comment: yes, I have used it too. I probably think `on` does better job and unexpected behavior like some parts of code not working even though all logic and syntax are correct are rarely seen using `on`

Comment: No, bind() is just as reliable as on() because it does exactly the same thing as on() - the actual implementation of bind() is just a call to on(). Using on() is thus very slightly more efficient *at the time of the call*, but makes no difference at all at the time the bound events occur, and makes no difference at all with "unexpected behaviour".

Comment: I have used `bind` few times only so not sure of the behavior. I depend on `on`. Maybe I would have written the logic or syntax wrong that time. Anyways that was the wonderful explanation you gave. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `event` parameter to your handler and check what event is raised

As you can see below: first - [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), then - [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)
So you should select just one of them.

---

This interesting, but seems *input* event for *select* raised just in Chrome.

---

Sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('textarea#modifyme').val('Some useless text');

    $('select#changemyvalue').on('change keyup input', function(e) {
    
        console.log('Now raised: '+e.type+' event');
        $("#events").append('Now raised: '+e.type+' event <br/>');
        // This is not displaying...
        $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="modifyme" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<select name="" id="changemyvalue">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="events"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I got the double alert trigger fixed, but last part of the code is still not functionning. I can't figure why the second .val('somestring') is not triggering... I'm trying to change a textarea displaying as a wysiwg editor, could this be the reason why I can't modify this after an event? Is it only possible to set this on page load?

Comment: And if I invert the order of these 2 lines  from :
    A-alert('I know you want to change text');
    B-$('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
to :
    B-$('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
    A-alert('I know you want to change text');

I got absolutely nothing running, alert is not showing and text area change is not happening...

Comment: @Poissonvert, in snippet above textarea value changed after select change?

Comment: Yes it did.
But I've got the point, wysihtml5 method is creating an iFrame in order to display the text value. I managed to change it with some heavy googling :)

Answer (score 0):

You Remove **keyup input**  on your Script

Try This Jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('textarea#modifyme').val('Some useless text');

$('select#changemyvalue').on('change', function(e) {

    // This alert triggers but twice
    alert('I know you want to change text');
    // This is not displaying...
    $('textarea#modifyme').val('I do not want to be display');
});
});
```